# PV Wave/IDL to MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a source code file from PV-Wave/IDL. I never used either of these programs, and hear that they are FORTRAN based, but I never used FORTRAN either. Problem is, I need to convert this file over to MATLAB.

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm not the greatest programmer, so go easy on me!

Answer (score 0):

have no experience with PV-Wave/IDL but ones I've converted the Fortran into Matlab with the aid of [f2matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5260) package by [Ben Barrowes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/12143). Try to query Ben maybe he get a clue.

Answer (score 0):

PV-Wave [documentation](https://www.roguewave.com/help-support/documentation/pv-wave) and [programmers guide](http://vis.lbl.gov/NERSC/Software/pvwave/docs/pdf/ProgrammersWAVE75.pdf). Using this you should be able to get a basic understanding of pv-wave, enough to then re-write simple programs in matlab. PV-Wave also has a debugger, so you can step through code which will undoubtedly help your understanding of the programs you need to re-write.

Comment: also useful [docs](http://vis.lbl.gov/NERSC/Software/pvwave/docs/pdf/TSWAVE30.pdf)